# Cloning multiple schemas into new schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to clone multiple schemas into 1 schema?

Assume I have the following schemas: `prod_ABC`, `prod_DEF`, and `prod_GHI`. I want all 3 cloned into `dev_XYZ`.

I can loop through and clone table by table (and view by view) using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, but I'm hoping for a more schema-level approach.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. You can only create one new schema, which is a clone of one of your source schemas. For the objects of the other two source schemas, you would need to loop the Information Schema and clone the tables into your target Schema on individual basis.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-clone.html